# Word Automization Service in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I am converting docx document to pdf. But it is not able to convert. I have check in sharepoint database it gives error code 3

What to do for that?

Answer (score 1):

> Code 3
>
> "The file could not be downloaded from the input library because the
>   supplied user permissions expired before the file could be retrieved.
>   This likely indicates that the system is under heavy load. Please try
>   resubmitting the job, and contact your system administrator if the
>   error reoccurs."

[Word Automation Services Error Messages and Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff512774%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Most likely the file you are trying to convert is too heavy and your login time-outs, mybe by ISA or TMG server.

OR

As described in the error, your system doesn't has resources to process convertion and times out with code-3. Try with a smaller file and see if it works.

Comment: I have try with 7KB file. But still it is not working

Comment: are you getting same error ? also does the application pool account has access to library you are trying to get document from

Comment: Yes. Application pool account has access and i am getting same wrror